# In IntelliJ how can I make it so that I use the same "Favorites" in different projects

Tags: intellij-idea, favorites

problem is that I have to checkout a different branch for every project. and while the paths are the same, I have to load favorites every time. Its a pain.

How can i get them to be the same on all projects?

(windows xp intellij 7.0.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea I had was to create a softlink using windows linkd.exe, but there may still be some problems with this approach as the file used to store the favorites data holds other project related meta data as well.